# StringTrim differently from left and right

Tags: functions, function-construction

Is there a function to trim a string with a different pattern for the left and right side? (I seem to remember it but perhaps I am thinking of another language because I can't find it in the documentation.)

Comment: It's already in the documentation [here for trimming the end of strings](https://wolfram.com/xid/0cg3cyrxa-g6n1gu) `StringTrim[str]` and [here for the start](https://wolfram.com/xid/0cg3cyrxa-f0k4w) `StringTrim["str", RegularExpression["^ *"]]`. You must be thinking of python which has `rstrip` and `lstrip`, but Mathematica has just a single documented trim function.

Answer (score 2):

[`StringTrim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTrim.html) and patterns combined with [`StartOfString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartOfString.html) or [`EndOfString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EndOfString.html), or [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) equivalant patterns, can trim from the left or right of strings. For example, use `StartOfString` and strings, patterns or regular expressions to trim only from the left (i.e, the start) of a string.

```
StringTrim["aaaXYZaaa", StartOfString~~"a"..] // FullForm
(* "XYZaaa" *)
StringTrim["aaaXYZaaa", RegularExpression["^a+"]] // FullForm
(* "XYZaaa" *)
```

Similarly, use `EndOfString` to trim only from the right (i.e., the end) of a string.

```
StringTrim["cccXYZccc", "c"..~~EndOfString] // FullForm
(* "cccXYZ" *)
StringTrim["cccXYZccc", RegularExpression["c+$"]] // FullForm
(* "cccXYZ" *)
```

We can combine `StartOfString` and `EndOfString` as [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) to trim differently both from the left and the right.

```
StringTrim["aaaXYZccc", ((StartOfString~~"a"..)|("c"..~~EndOfString))] // FullForm
(* "XYZ" *)
```

### Function to Trim Left and Right

Here's a function that removes differently from the left and the right of a string. Use the pattern-matching capabilities of `StringTrim`.

```
ClearAll[stringTrimEnds]
stringTrimEnds[s_?StringQ, patt1_, patt2_] := StringTrim[s,
  ((StartOfString~~patt1)|(patt2~~EndOfString))]
```

### Examples

Each of these examples returns "XYZ".

1. Use strings to remove "abc" from the left, and "def" from the right.
2. Use patterns to remove `Whitespace` from the left, and any length
   string of "c" from the right.
3. Remove anything that is not "X" from the left, and any length of "a"
   or "b" from the right.
4. Remove all digit characters (numbers) from the left, and a string
   that matches hours, minutes and seconds from the right.

```
(*1*) stringTrimEnds["abcXYZdef", "abc", "def"] // FullForm
(*2*) stringTrimEnds["   XYZccc", Whitespace, "c"..] // FullForm
(*3*) stringTrimEnds["a2cXYZabb",
        RegularExpression["[^X]+"], RegularExpression["[ab]+"]] // FullForm
(*4*) stringTrimEnds["123XYZ12:14:35",
        DigitCharacter.., DatePattern[{"Hour","Minute","Second"}]] // FullForm
```